# Unity3D move a sprite when pressing a key

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, game-physics

I'm trying to move a sprite when I hit the `w` key. I have been using a tutorial I found on  YouTube and I don't seem to able to make it work. Here is the code. Perhaps I'm having a problem with the Transform; I can see that the x position increments but the sprite doesn't do anything.

```
#pragma strict

var startPoint : Vector3;
var endPoint : Vector3;
var speed : float;
private var increment : float;
var isMoving : boolean;

function Start ()
{
    startPoint = transform.position;
    endPoint = transform.position;
}

function Update ()
{
    if (increment <= 1 && isMoving == true) {
        increment += speed/100;
        Debug.Log("Moving");

    }
    else {
        isMoving = false;
        Debug.Log("Stopped");

    }

    if (isMoving == true)
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, increment);

    if (Input.GetKey("w") && isMoving == false) {
        increment = 0;
        isMoving = true;
        startPoint = transform.position;
        endPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + 1);

    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s") && isMoving == false) {
        increment = 0;
        isMoving = true;
        startPoint = transform.position;
        endPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want your sprite to move in the z axis?

Comment: Yes, when I manually write in the Transform panel a number in the Z axis, the sprite really moves how its supposed to.

Comment: I think your script is a little bit complex to just move your sprite. There are any special way you want your spring to move, or its basically a simple move?

Comment: Im open to any ideas, i'm just following a tutorial. Any ideas? I just want to move my character (for now) one position up

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
        increment += speed / 100;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.forward, increment);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) {
        increment += speed / 100;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.back, increment);
    }
}
```

Also, check that your speed is not 0 in the inspector. If you wanna a continuous movement change Input.GetKeyDown to Input.GetKey.

Comment: Sorry to be so new in Unity, but what is the inspector and how do I check it? Perhaps that is the problem. I believe the Input is fine since I can the value of Z changing, but visually it stays in the same position.

Comment: This is the inspector: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Inspector.html. Click in the object that you've attached the script and you will see its properties on the inspector.

Comment: Ah Yes, the inspector changes the Z position + 1 when I press w, but I dont see the sprite moving

Comment: Can you see your script on the inspector?

Comment: It was the speed! Thanks you so much! It was set to zero! Thankssss

Comment: You're welcome. I would also recommend you to watch the unity3d official tutorials: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules. And accept my answer please